# Como obter a os valores das keys de um objeto KeyValuePair c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, asp.net-core

Posuo um Json com a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
 "Data" {
     "Request": [
      {
        "text": "Minha Pergunta?",
        "response": "Minha resposta"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Faço da seguinte forma para receber os valores no código:

```
IConfigurationSection result = _config.GetSection("Data").GetSection("Request");
var itemArray = result.AsEnumerable();
string valor;
```

Depois, faço um foreach para percorrer a lista toda:

```
foreach (var item in itemArray)
   {
      valor = item.Value
   }
```

Porém, dessa forma a variavel `valor` está recebendo o value da propriedade `text` do meu array no json. Preciso receber o valor que está em `response`

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível navegar pelas keys, e uma opição é usar um `Dictionary`. Aproveitando isso, se a estrutura é sempre a mesma nos values (text, response), pode criar uma classe com essa estrutura e usar um objeto tipado, muito mais fácil de navegar e iterar, por exemplo:

```
public class RequestData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

E fazer o cast do da `Section` tipando, assim:

```
var result = _config
    .GetSection("Data")
    .Get<IDictionary<string, IList<RequestData>>>();
```

E navegar assim:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("================");
    foreach(var subItem in item.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{subItem.Text}: {subItem.Response}");
    }
}
```

Pode ver um exemplo funcinando, adaptado para uma string json aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HDD1un

Comment: Boa, funcionou, muito obrigado